# Access denied to S3 when using COPY command with IAM role

Tags: amazon-redshift, amazon-iam

I have the following copy command:

```
copy ink.contact_trace_records
from 's3://mybucket/mykey'
iam_role 'arn:aws:iam::accountnum:role/rolename'
json 'auto';
```

Where the role has the full access to S3 and full access to RS policies (I know this is not a good idea, but I'm just losing it here :) ). The cluster has the role attached. The cluster has VPC enhanced routing. I get the following:

```
[2019-05-28 14:07:34] [XX000][500310] [Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: S3ServiceException:Access Denied,Status 403,Error AccessDenied,Rid 370F75618922AFC0,ExtRid dp2mcnlofFzt4dz00Lcm188/+ta3OEKVpuFjnZSYsC0pJPMiULk7I6spOpiZwXc04VVRdxizIj4=,CanRetry 1
[2019-05-28 14:07:34] Details:
[2019-05-28 14:07:34] -----------------------------------------------
[2019-05-28 14:07:34] error:  S3ServiceException:Access Denied,Status 403,Error AccessDenied,Rid 370F75618922AFC0,ExtRid dp2mcnlofFzt4dz00Lcm188/+ta3OEKVpuFjnZSYsC0pJPMiULk7I6spOpiZwXc04VVRdxizIj4=,CanRetry 1
[2019-05-28 14:07:34] code:      8001
[2019-05-28 14:07:34] context:   S3 key being read : s3://redacted
[2019-05-28 14:07:34] query:     7794423
[2019-05-28 14:07:34] location:  table_s3_scanner.cpp:372
[2019-05-28 14:07:34] process:   query3_986_7794423 [pid=13695]
[2019-05-28 14:07:34] -----------------------------------------------;
```

What am I missing here? The cluster has full access to S3, it is not even in a custom VPC, it is in the default one. Thoughts?

Comment: Could be a few reasons. The bucket could be in a different account (hence no permissions). The object with the given `key` might not exist (there is no "file not found" error, it comes through as Access Denied). Also, Redshift normally expects to load all objects in a given directory, but you appear to be specifying a particular object. Try pointing to the directory (ending with `/`) rather than the specific key. (Yes, it should work both ways, but it is worth trying.)

Comment: You have Enhanced VPC Routing enabled, so have you created a VPC endpoint for S3? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/enhanced-vpc-working-with-endpoints.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Check the object owner.** The object is likely owned by another account. This is the reason for S3 403s in many situations where objects cannot be accessed by a role or account that has full permissions. The typical indicator is that you can `list` the object(s) but cannot `get` or `head` them.

In the following example I'm trying to access a Redshift audit log from a 2nd account. The account `012345600000` is granted access to the bucket owned by `999999999999` using the following policy:

```
{"Version": "2012-10-17",
 "Statement": [
        {"Action": [
                "s3:Get*",
                "s3:ListBucket*"
            ],
          "Effect": "Allow",
          "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::my-audit-logs",
                "arn:aws:s3:::my-audit-logs/*"
            ],
          "Principal": {
                "AWS": [
                    "arn:aws:iam::012345600000:root"
                ]}}]
 }
```

Now I try to list (`s3 ls`) then copy (`s3 cp`) a single log object:

```
aws --profile 012345600000 s3 ls s3://my-audit-logs/AWSLogs/999999999999/redshift/us-west-2/2019/05/25/
# 2019-05-28 14:49:46        376 …connectionlog_2019-05-25T19:03.gz
aws --profile 012345600000 s3 cp s3://my-audit-logs/AWSLogs/999999999999/redshift/us-west-2/2019/05/25/…connectionlog_2019-05-25T19:03.gz ~/Downloads/…connectionlog_2019-05-25T19:03.gz
# fatal error: An error occurred (403) when calling the HeadObject operation: Forbidden
```

Then I check the object ownership from the account that owns the bucket.

```
aws --profile 999999999999 s3api get-object-acl --bucket my-audit-logs --key AWSLogs/999999999999/redshift/us-west-2/2019/05/25/…connectionlog_2019-05-25T19:03.gz
# "Owner": {
#    "DisplayName": "aws-cm-prod-auditlogs-uswest2", ## Not my account!
#    "ID": "b2b456ce30a967fb1877b3c9594773ae0275fee248e3ebdbff43d66907b89144"
# },
```

I then copy the object in the same bucket with `--acl bucket-owner-full-control`. This makes me the owner of the new object. Note the changed `SharedLogs/` prefix.

```
aws --profile 999999999999 s3 cp \ 
   s3://my-audit-logs/AWSLogs/999999999999/redshift/us-west-2/2019/05/25/…connectionlog_2019-05-25T19:03.gz \
   s3://my-audit-logs/SharedLogs/999999999999/redshift/us-west-2/2019/05/25/…connectionlog_2019-05-25T19:03.gz \
   --acl bucket-owner-full-control
```

Now I can download (or load to Redshift!) the new object that is shared from the same bucket.

```
aws --profile 012345600000 s3 cp s3://my-audit-logs/SharedLogs/999999999999/redshift/us-west-2/2019/05/25/…connectionlog_2019-05-25T19:03.gz ~/Downloads/…connectionlog_2019-05-25T19:03.gz
# download: …
```

Comment: Oh god, I didn't know an object could have a different owner even though it is in my account.. `--acl bucket-owner-full-control` is the real life saver here. Thanks!